# How can i css style a button in amp page?

Tags: amp-html

How can I style the free house valuation button in this amp page https://www.housesinsale.co.uk/17-great-alternatives-to-rightmove-today/?amp ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS below the `Paste your Custom CSS` line (usually found at the end) since AMP requires you to inline *all* style rules.

You'll need to ensure said inline CSS **does not** exceed 50 kilobytes.

**Resources:**

- [How AMP Works](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/about-how)
- [Supported CSS](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages)